# AS3 Getting a non-framed Var

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I know that this is a noob question, but I've started using as3 a week ago, and, all I need to do is get a var value of a frame as3 to another frame, like:

Frame1, layer1: `var points:int = 0;`
Frame2, layer1: What can I do to get the 'points' value?

Sorry if this is a repeated question, I'm brazilian and, I've probably searched everything wrong, as wrong as I probably write this question, bye :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing.

The variable declared on a previous frame should still exist on the next frame. What do you get when you try this on frame 2:

```
trace(points);
```

Comment: thanks, and Just 1 thig, if I (I don't know how) declare the var again in another frame, it will return a bug, the first or it will overwrite the first?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Coding on frames is not recommended anyway and I stopped doing it several years ago. I'd say just give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Despite not being recommended, I found it easier to code on different timeline frames. Here's the solution of Your problem (I think). I'm storing values, that need to be shared on every frame, in a layer that timeline-wise spreads on all frames ("shared" on the pic). Then I read those values on next frames, placing the code on an another layer ("code" on the pic). I hope that's more or less understandable.

[image: What I did]